# Finding the distance of coordinates from the beginning of a route in Shapely

Tags: python, geometry, distance, shapely

I have a list of coordinates (lat/lon) representing a route. 
Given a certain radius and another coordinate I need to check if the coord is in the route (within the given radius from any point) and its distance from the beginning of the route.

I looked at Shapely and it looks like a good solution.

I started off by creating a `StringLine`

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
route = LineString[(x, y), (x1, y1), ...]
```

Then to check if the point is near the route I've added a buffer and checked 
for intersection

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
p = Point(x, y)
r = 0.5
intersection = p.buffer(r).intersection(route)
if intersection.is_empty: 
    print "Point not on route"
else: 
    # Calculate P distance from the begning of route
```

I'm stuck calculating the distance. I thought of splitting the route at `p` and measuring the length of the first half but the intersection result I get is a `HeterogeneousGeometrySequence` which I'm not sure what I can do with.

I believe I found a solution:

```
if p.buffer(r).intersects(route):
 return route.project(p)
```

Comment: If you've got the coordinates of starting and final point, you can simply use the distance formula: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Comment: Hey @Afaan Bilal, I'm no geo expert but i belive that simple distance calculations are not 100% accurate for geo calculations (world is round ... ). Plus, I'm looking for a complete solution using some kind of package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than buffering a geometry, which is expensive and imperfect (since buffering requires a number of segments and [many other options](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.buffer)), just see if the point is within a distance threshold:

```
if route.distance(p) <= r:
    return route.project(p)
```

Also, you probably realised by now that your distance units are in degrees. If you want linear distances, like meters, you would need to make it much more complicated using different libraries.

Comment: Hey @Mike T, Thanks for the comment i've already removed the buffer in favour of plain distance. Can you recomand a lightweight package (or another implementatin in python) for converting the distances to meters ?

Comment: @haki that's actually a complicated question requiring lots of info, such as how big the region is and what precision is acceptable. There are [a few methods in this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80881/1872), which may work, but there are several others not listed there such as calculating geodesics with either Vincenty's formulae or more precise [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks @Mike T. If in understand correctly as long as i'm calculating distances in small areas the diversion will not be significant. I'm currently multiplying by 100K to get meters. I've starred the question you linked so i could get to it when i get a chance. Thanks again.

Comment: For small scales, the normal approach is to find out what UTM zone the route is [mostly] within, reproject the route and point into that UTM zone, then do the Cartesian distances with Shapely. On-the-fly projections are pretty quick, but take a bit of care to make sure they are set-up correctly.